# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, jupyter-lab

Python version

```
C:\Users\donhu>python --version
Python 3.11.0

C:\Users\donhu>
```

I try install PyTorch, but catch error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
```

I also try with Jupyter lab, and other version of PyTorch (nightly build), but not success.

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ (Updated 11/27/2023)

> Currently, PyTorch on Windows only supports Python 3.8-3.11; Python 2.x is not supported.